# How can I get a custom authentication filter working in Grails?

Tags: grails, groovy, spring-security

I have an app written in Grails 3 which uses the Spring Security plugin to allow for both session-based and basic authentication. My `application.groovy` file includes the following (sanitized):

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.targetUrlParameter = 'r'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.useBasicAuth = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.useSwitchUserFilter = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.postOnly = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.anon.key = '123456789'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.basic.realmName = "My Company, LLC"
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.usernamePropertyName = 'email'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'com.mydomain.user.User'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'com.mydomain.user.UserRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'com.mydomain.user.Role'
```

We're going to be adding integration for an external service that sends JWTs, so I wrote a custom filter and custom authentication provider that can handle the specific JWT claims that are being sent. And I'm halfway there - I can add it to the filter chain and the list of providers and the JWT-based authentication does work. So that's good news.

However, as soon as I do that, the original session-based authentication **stops working**. So in addition to the bit above from `application.groovy`, I also add this:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.filterNames = [
    'securityRequestHolderFilter',
    'statelessSecurityContextPersistenceFilter',
    'logoutFilter',
    'authenticationProcessingFilter',
    'basicAuthenticationFilter',
    'jwtAuthFilter',
    'securityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter',
    'rememberMeAuthenticationFilter',
    'anonymousAuthenticationFilter',
    'exceptionTranslationFilter',
    'basicExceptionTranslationFilter',
    'filterInvocationInterceptor',
    'switchUserProcessingFilter',
]
grails.plugin.springsecurity.providerNames = [
    'daoAuthenticationProvider',
    'anonymousAuthenticationProvider',
    'rememberMeAuthenticationProvider',
    'jwtAuthenticationProvider',
]
```

And I define those new beans explicitly in `resources.groovy`:

```
beans = {
    // ...other bean definitions...
    jwtAuthFilter(JwtAuthFilter)
    jwtAuthenticationProvider(JwtAuthenticationProvider)
}
```

But like I said, while this does work - my custom JwtAuthFilter class gets invoked and correctly processes the incoming JWTs - the session-based authentication has stopped working completely. So I tried commenting out all the references to jwtAuthFilter and jwtAuthenticationProvider, but leaving the explicit list of `filterNames` and `providerNames` in `application.groovy` in place. Unfortunately, that too results in the session-based authentication not working. So it seems to have something to do with explicitly specifying the list of filters and providers.

Unfortunately, I can't tell the difference between what's going on under-the-hood when I explicitly list out the filters vs. when I don't. As far as I can tell they should be identical, but clearly they're not since the auth fails. How can I get this working?

Answer (score 0):

To add jwt authentication to a grails application that already uses spring security core plugin, I suggest you to use the grails-spring-security-rest plugin http://alvarosanchez.github.io/grails-spring-security-rest/latest/docs/
But if you prefer your own implementation perhaps the config section of the plugin helps and matches your needs, it use the **grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap**  in **application.groovy**

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
    //Stateless chain
    [
            pattern: '/**',
            filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS,-anonymousAuthenticationFilter,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter'
    ],

    //Traditional, stateful chain
    [
            pattern: '/stateful/**',
            filters: 'JOINED_FILTERS,-restTokenValidationFilter,-restExceptionTranslationFilter'
    ]
]
```